# ERROR while opening PDF file in unity via button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

THE ERROR:

Assets\DemoScript.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityAndroidOpenUrl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Following is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityAndroidOpenUrl;
using UnityEngine;

public class DemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
 private const string MAIN_DIR = "/storage/emulated/0";
 private const string testFolderName = "Download";
 private const string templatePDFName = "user_manual.pdf";

private static string pathToTestFolder;
private static string pathToTemplatePDF;

private void Start()
{
    pathToTestFolder = Path.Combine(MAIN_DIR, testFolderName);
    if (!Directory.Exists(pathToTestFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToTestFolder);
    }

    StartCoroutine(SaveTemplatePDF());
}

private IEnumerator SaveTemplatePDF()
{
    string localPathToTemplatePDF = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, templatePDFName);
    WWW www = new WWW(localPathToTemplatePDF);
    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error while loading template PDF: " + www.error);
        yield break;
    }
    pathToTemplatePDF = Path.Combine(pathToTestFolder, templatePDFName);
    File.WriteAllBytes(pathToTemplatePDF, www.bytes);

    AndroidOpenUrl.OpenFile(pathToTemplatePDF);
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know much about Unity, but a Google search for `UnityAndroidOpenUrl` turned up nothing. Are you sure that's correct? I found a lot of references to `Application.OpenUrl()`...

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Unity.Android.OpenUrl`?

Comment: Application.OpenURL() does not work any more when trying to open files locally as per Unity documentation thats why i am trying the other way round.                           
                                                                                                                               Android: Due security changes in Android 7.0 (More information), Application.OpenURL can no longer be used for opening local app files, you need to use FileProvider which allows you to share files with other applications.